# JS sort array with strings&string numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort array with custom values, by it's integer value.
There is my array:

```
[ 'a>46', 'a>86', 'h>78' ]
```

And desired output:

```
[ 'a>46', 'h>78', 'a>86' ]
```

Note: the largest possible value to be found in my array is 90.

I'm trying this way:

```
  var newarr = [];
  var max = 91;
          for (let u = 0; u < array.length; u++) {
            var nmbr = parseInt(array[u].replace(/\D/g,'')); // get integer of array element

            if (nmbr < max) {       // if element is lower than current highest value
              max = nmbr;
              newarr[0] = array[u];  // assign it to the beggining of new array
            } else {   // else put it at as the next newarr element

              newarr[newarr.lenght+1] = array[u];
            }

          }
```

Output:

```
[ 'a>46', <1 empty item>, 'a>86' ]
```

Comment: what is supposed to be `minutsy` can you add a snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using `Array.prototype.sort()`.

```
var array = ["a>46", "h>78", "a>86"]
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  var number_a = parseInt(a.replace(/\D/g,''));
  var number_b = parseInt(b.replace(/\D/g,''));
  return number_a - number_b;
});
```

Outputs `["a>46", "h>78", "a>86"]`

---

if you wanna learn more about how this actually works I recommend checking out the `compare` function example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Basically: if you return zero, then `a` and `b` are equal. if you return a negative number that means `a` is less than `b`. if you return a positive number that means `a` is greater than `b`.

Comment: This works, but the replace method return ">46" which includes the `>` sign.

Comment: may need to consider this kind of case `var array = ["a2>46", "h1>78", "a0>86"]`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected reult, use below option of using array sort function

```js
var array = [ 'a>46', 'a>86', 'h>78' ]


console.log(array.sort((a,b) => a.substring(2) - b.substring(2)));
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/eLdYKz?editors=1010

Comment: Note that this answer uses implicit conversion, which may be confusing at first glance.

Comment: as per SO, comparison happens by integer values after '>' , using parseInt will do and even if it is not used , it work due to implicit conversion as mentioned by you

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript comes with a built in method to sort arrays.

```js
const array = [ 'a>46', 'a>86', 'h>78' ];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  a = Number.parseInt(a.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
  b = Number.parseInt(b.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
  return a - b;
});

console.log(array);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt